# I would like to know how to display the data on the website after being fetched via ajax

Tags: rest

```
$.ajax({
               url: "http://bc-net/Sandbox/juandev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Qlinks')/items",
               method: "GET",
               headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
               success: function (data) {
               var items = data.d.results;

                    if (items.length > 0 ) {
                         //This section can be used to iterate through data and show it on screen

                    }
                    console.log(items);       
              },
              error: function (data) {
                  alert("Error: "+ data);
             }
      });
```

The console shows I have fetched the items that live on the list but I am not sure how to inject them on the website.

Comment: In what format do you want to show this data? I guess it is upto you, how you want to show these data.....You can use HTML and CSS for that.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are pulling your data with JQuery's $.ajax method and you have set up an if statement to check for data. Make sure your data is parsed in to a JavaScript object and not still a JSON string. If it's an object you can continue, if it is still a string, use:

```
JSON.parse(data.d.results);
```

I assume you want to then loop through your list items and display them on the page. If you haven't already, you need to place a Web Part on the page to put some HTML in there that you can use to display your data. You can use either the Script Editor, the Content Editor or the Embed Script option if your page allows that. Place this HTML in there:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Now you are going to need to modify your code block to loop through your data and attach some HTML to your div element. Try the following in your if statement:

```
var el = document.getElementById("myDiv"); // get your div
var html = "<ul>"; // start a list

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { // loop through your data
    html += "<li>" + items[i].Title + "</li>";
}

html += "</ul>"; // end your list
el.innerHTML = html; // place your html in your div
```

This will make an un-ordered list to display the Titles of all your list items on your page.